# SpringBoot not seeing OpenAPI generated controllers

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm generating controller interfaces with `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`. The code is generated succesfully and I create controllers that implement generated interfaces.
But the problem is that Spring doesn't see these controllers at all.

My pom.xml with plugin config:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-api</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>
                                ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi/notification-settings/notification-settings-controller.yaml
                            </inputSpec>

                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <library>spring-boot</library>
                            <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>

                            <apiPackage>com.epam.stts.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.epam.stts.model</modelPackage>

                            <importMappings>
                                ChannelType=com.epam.stts.type.ChannelType,
                                NotificationSettingsType=com.epam.stts.type.NotificationSettingsType,
                                Period=com.epam.stts.component.Period
                            </importMappings>

                            <configOptions>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                                <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                                <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                                <useOptional>false</useOptional>

                                <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                                    @lombok.Data
                                    @lombok.NoArgsConstructor
                                    @lombok.AllArgsConstructor
                                    @lombok.Builder
                                </additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And generated interface is:

```java
    @Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen")
    @Validated
    @Tag(name = "notification-settings", description = "the notification-settings API")
    public interface NotificationSettingsApi {
    
        /**
         * GET /notification-settings : Get user&#39;s notification settings
         *
         * @param userId ID of user (required)
         * @return OK (status code 200)
         */
        @Operation(
            operationId = "getUserNotificationSettings",
            summary = "Get user's notification settings",
            responses = {
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK", content = {
                    @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = NotificationSettingsInfo.class))
                })
            }
        )
        @RequestMapping(
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            value = "/notification-settings",
            produces = { "application/json" }
        )
        ResponseEntity<List<NotificationSettingsInfo>> getUserNotificationSettings(
            @Parameter(name = "userId", description = "ID of user", required = true) @PathVariable("userId") Long userId
        );
    
    
        /**
         * POST /notification-settings/save : Save notification settings
         *
         * @param notificationSettingsInfo NotificationSettingsInfo request body (optional)
         * @return OK (status code 200)
         *         or Validation exception while mapping request body (status code 400)
         */
        @Operation(
            operationId = "saveNotificationSettings",
            summary = "Save notification settings",
            responses = {
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK", content = {
                    @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = Object.class))
                }),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Validation exception while mapping request body", content = {
                    @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = Object.class))
                })
            }
        )
        @RequestMapping(
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            value = "/notification-settings/save",
            produces = { "application/json" },
            consumes = { "application/json" }
        )
        ResponseEntity<Object> saveNotificationSettings(
            @Parameter(name = "NotificationSettingsInfo", description = "NotificationSettingsInfo request body") @Valid @RequestBody(required = false) NotificationSettingsInfo notificationSettingsInfo
        );
    
    }
```

Controller just implements the interface and makes calls to actual service etc.
But when I start the application (or perform any MVC test) I just get HTTP 404 while trying to make some requests to this controller.

I have no idea of what is wrong here and I can't figure out what is missing.

Will be grateful for any help.

UPDATE:

I figured it out. Added additional `<useSpringController>` tag to plugin configuration so generated interfaces are now annotated with `@Controller`.
And now it works.

Comment: Add a constructor with some log or breakpoint to the controller to ensure it has been loaded. If it hasn't, check the package or the configuration of your application (supposing it's autodetecting beans)

Comment: Yes, it has been loaded, I can see it in context. But it's not considered as a controller or something like that. Even when I open swagger I can't see any endpoints related to this controller.

Comment: show us your implementation. Did you added `@RestController` to the implementation?

Comment: Yes, my implementation is annotated with `@RestController` as well as `@RequestMapping`. 
But I figured out, I needed to annotate generated interface as `@Controller` as well. That is strange for me because I thought it would be enough annotation on implementation itself. But it works.

Answer (score 2):

This tag `<interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>` prevents openapi-generator generating controllers.

Comment: to fix `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'prodSummaryParserController' method`

add in `<configOptions><interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>`